# can't load Tensorflow v1 model in tensorflow V2 with update code?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I have saved model with .ckpt and .h5 format where my folder contain 4 file.

if i load in version 1 using command

```
model.load("model.ckpt") or model.load("model.h5")
```

and it's load successful in Tensorflow Version1 but while load in tensorflow version 2 it's showing error

```
  tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5') or  tf.keras.models.load_model('model.ckpt')
```

sometimes giving error

```
SavedModel file does not exist at: /model/model.ckpt/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

or sometime giving error

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'model.ckpt', errno = 2, error message = 
'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

i double check path i upload in google colab and give exact location but not working.

here is my code link

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hf7AwEMJHf4zLZOBSzxejA2ISuTQ3N9K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is inside a folder in your drive then add your folder's name in the path. otherwise use the code as it is.

```
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
model_file_name = os.path.join("/content/gdrive/My Drive", 'model.h5')# CHANGE MODEL NAME
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file_name)
```

On execution it will show a link click on it and choose your drive account where the file is located, then copy paste the key in your program.

Comment: Thanks Rishabh I try but not working i am sharing my model link that you can download and try by yourself if you can help me ....                                                             (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tPoUDM5Re3ZKXwK2f7kbzwK8Lad6vtCX)

Comment: I try this code  ** import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
model_file_name = os.path.join("my_drive/AI_values/model", 'AI_value.h5')# CHANGE MODEL NAME
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file_name) **